# Bug: table shows correctly while editing question, but not after posting it

Tags: bug

I have taken a look at [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136077/having-2-sets-of-distances-in-undirected-weighted-tree-get-all-of-the-edges?noredirect=1#comment286586_136077), and as you can clearly see - it looks quite horrible in fact. *But*, the author mentioned that in "edit mode" it looks correctly, so I also checked it out.

There is a **big** difference between the preview and the actual post. In the post, the table just does not render at all!

I'm new here in the meta, so I'm sorry if this is not how the meta should be used. Thanks in advance!